# Google chrome sending string instead of number

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, fckeditor, numberformatexception

I am facing one issue with respect to browser compatibility.
I get following error when I work with one of the form in my struts project.
[image]

**EDIT:**

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm actionForm,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        MemorialPrintForm form = (MemorialPrintForm) actionForm;
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
        DbUserSession sessionUser = SessionHelpers.getUserSession(request);
        DatabaseTransaction t = null;
        fdms.ui.struts.form.EditVerseForm editVerse = null;
        String submitType = form.getDirective();
        logger.debug("ProcessMemorialPrint submit = "+submitType);

        if (sessionUser == null)    {
            errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("error.login.invalid"));
        }

        if (submitType.equals("cancel")) {
            ActionForward actionForward = mapping.findForward("openCase");
            return actionForward;
        }

        if ((submitType.equals("edit") || submitType.equals("copy") || submitType.equals("remove")) && (form.getVerse() == null || form.getVerse().trim().length() == 0)) {
            errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("error.tables.noselect"));
        }

        if (submitType.equals("print") && ((form.getFormat() == null || form.getFormat().trim().length() == 0) || (form.getVerse() == null || form.getVerse().trim().length() == 0))) {
            errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("error.tables.noselect"));
        }

        try {
            t = (DatabaseTransaction)DatabaseTransaction.getTransaction(sessionUser);

            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                DbVitalsDeceased dbVitals = FdmsDb.getInstance().getVitalsDeceased(t, SessionHelpers.getVitalsIdFromSession(request, sessionUser));
                DbMemorial[] dbMemorial = FdmsDb.getInstance().getMemorialSet(t, sessionUser.getRegion());
                DbFormsAvailable[] dbFormsAvailable = FdmsDb.getInstance().getFormsAvailableForLocale(t, sessionUser.getRegion(), DbFormsAvailable.MEMORIAL_TYPE);
                fdms.ui.struts.form.MemorialPrintForm memorialPrint = new fdms.ui.struts.form.MemorialPrintForm();
                java.util.ArrayList formatList = new java.util.ArrayList();
                java.util.ArrayList verseList = new java.util.ArrayList();

                memorialPrint.setVitalsId(String.valueOf(dbVitals.getId()));
                memorialPrint.setDeceasedFullName(dbVitals.getDecFullName());

                if (memorialPrint.getDeceasedFullName() == null || memorialPrint.getDeceasedFullName().trim().length() == 0) {
                    memorialPrint.setDeceasedFullName(dbVitals.getDecFName() +" " +dbVitals.getDecMName() +" " +dbVitals.getDecLName());
                }

                //Populate the format List
                for (int i=0; i < dbFormsAvailable.length; i++) {
                    String listValue = String.valueOf(dbFormsAvailable[i].getId());
                    String listLabel = dbFormsAvailable[i].getDescription();
                    formatList.add(new OptionsList(listValue, listLabel));
                }

                //Populate the Verse List
                for (int i=0; i < dbMemorial.length; i++) {
                    String listValue = String.valueOf(dbMemorial[i].getId());
                    String listLabel = dbMemorial[i].getDescription();
                    verseList.add(new OptionsList(listValue, listLabel));
                }

                // Clean up
                t.closeConnection();
                request.setAttribute("memorialPrint", memorialPrint);
                request.setAttribute("formatList", formatList);
                request.setAttribute("verseList", verseList);
                saveErrors(request, errors);
                return (new ActionForward(mapping.getInput()));
            }

            editVerse = new fdms.ui.struts.form.EditVerseForm();
            editVerse.setVitalsId(form.getVitalsId());

            if (!form.getDirective().equals("add")) {
                try {
                    DbMemorial dbMemorial = FdmsDb.getInstance().getMemorial(t, Integer.parseInt(form.getVerse()));
                    if (dbMemorial != null) {
                        if (submitType.equals("remove")) {
                            dbMemorial.remove();
                            t.addPersistent(dbMemorial);
                            t.save();
                        } else {
                            editVerse.setDescription(dbMemorial.getDescription());
                            if (form.getDirective().equals("edit")) {
                                editVerse.setMemorialId(String.valueOf(dbMemorial.getId()));
                            }
                            editVerse.setVitalsId(form.getVitalsId());
                            editVerse.setTextValue(dbMemorial.getVerse());

                            // Set form into request scope
                            request.setAttribute("editVerse", editVerse);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

        } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
            logger.error("Persistence Exception in ProcessMemorialPrint.doPerform. " + pe);
            errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("error.PersistenceException", pe.getCause()));
            t.closeConnection();

        } catch(Exception pe) {
            logger.error("Exception in ProcessMemorialPrint.doPerform. ", pe);
            errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("error.GeneralException", pe.getMessage()));
            t.closeConnection();
        } finally {
            if ( t != null ) {
                t.closeConnection();
            }
        }

        //Action Forward Logic
        ActionForward actionForward = mapping.findForward("editVerse");

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            //AppLog.info("ProcessMemorialPrint Invoking forward mapping getInput() ");
            saveErrors(request, errors );
            actionForward = new ActionForward(mapping.getInput());
        }

        if (submitType.equals("remove")) {
            actionForward = mapping.findForward("showMemorialPrint");
        }

        //AppLog.trace("Leaving ProcessMemorialPrint.");
        return actionForward;

    }
```

**Full Stack Trace:**

```
2015-08-26 10:52:37,024 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/webfdms].[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "chrome/"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at com.fredck.FCKeditor.FCKeditor.retrieveBrowserVersion(FCKeditor.java:264)
    at com.fredck.FCKeditor.FCKeditor.isCompatible(FCKeditor.java:251)
    at com.fredck.FCKeditor.FCKeditor.create(FCKeditor.java:292)
    at com.fredck.FCKeditor.tags.FCKeditorTag.doAfterBody(FCKeditorTag.java:689)
    at org.apache.jsp.EditVerse_jsp._jspService(EditVerse_jsp.java:258)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at fdms.ui.ActionTimmingFilter.doFilter(ActionTimmingFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at fdms.ui.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-26 10:52:37,028 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/webfdms].[WebFDMS]] Servlet.service() for servlet WebFDMS threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "chrome/"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at com.fredck.FCKeditor.FCKeditor.retrieveBrowserVersion(FCKeditor.java:264)
    at com.fredck.FCKeditor.FCKeditor.isCompatible(FCKeditor.java:251)
    at com.fredck.FCKeditor.FCKeditor.create(FCKeditor.java:292)
    at com.fredck.FCKeditor.tags.FCKeditorTag.doAfterBody(FCKeditorTag.java:689)
    at org.apache.jsp.EditVerse_jsp._jspService(EditVerse_jsp.java:258)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at fdms.ui.ActionTimmingFilter.doFilter(ActionTimmingFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at fdms.ui.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But the same thing worked out with Mozilla Firefox.
What may be the issue? It seems to be a browser compatibility.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post full stack trace from your console or log file.

Comment: @NamanGala I have added full stack trace from my log file. please have a look.

Comment: is `FCKeditor` your class?

Comment: yes my jsp are using it

Comment: Post `FCKeditor.retrieveBrowserVersion()` method and also point out line line 264 in FCKeditor.java

Comment: @NamanGala I dont have FCKeditor.java but I have fckeditor.js file

Comment: I won't be able to help you further. Let others help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the `FCKEditor` library, which doesn't handle what Chrome returns properly.

You would need to either load a newer version where the bug has been fixed (if one exists), or extract the source code for the library and fix it yourself.

I recommend going to the [Author's home page](http://ckeditor.com/users/fredck) to see if you can find help there.